# Обновление Ubuntu 14.04 до 15.04 не обновляет информацию в uname -a

Tags: linux, ubuntu, update

Изначально была Ubuntu 14.04 > 14.10 > 15.04

В сведениях о системе вижу 15.04, но uname -a показывает

> 3.16.0-48-generic #64~14.04.1-Ubuntu

Так и должно быть? По идее там должно быть 15!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

насколько я понимаю, то, что вы привели — это строчка из названия пакета с программой *linux*, причём именно той версии, которая сейчас загружена в оперативную память.

а пакеты могут быть установлены из разных версий разных дистрибутивов. хуже того — ничто (кроме здравого смысла) не сможет помешать вам разложить по файловой системе файлы и каталоги, не относящиеся вообще ни к какому пакету.

в поисках информации, на какую версию какого дистрибутива больше всего похожа (в настоящий момент) используемая вами система, я бы предложил больше опираться на результаты выполнения программы `lsb_release` с опцией `-a` (приведён пример вывода на одной из машин, где когда-то была установлена одна из версий дистрибутива *ubuntu*):

```
$ lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

Comment: Можно также `cat /etc/issue` У меня пишет `Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS \n \l`